# state transition with different guard condition

Tags: uml, state-machine, state-pattern

In the state pattern how is this modeled ?

state A to state B on trigger X and conditon C1 when current state is A

state A to state C on trigger X and condition C2 when current state is A

how is this usually accomplished ? I have a lot of guard conditions that I may need to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty standard see e.g. [this example](http://www.sparxsystems.com/resources/uml2_tutorial/uml2_statediagram.html).

[Edited on basis it's not homework!]

Assuming I understand right:

- You have one event (`X`) which can trigger one of two possible transitions
- Selecting which transition to fire is made according to which condition holds true (`C1` or `C2`)

If so that's a standard case for using guard conditions.  The syntax would be:

- `X[C1]` as the label on the transition A->B, and
- `X[C2]` on the transition A->C.

C1 & C2 must evaluate to booleans, so it would be fine to substitute `var==2` as per your comment.  i.e. the labels would become `X[var==2]` and `X[var==3]`.

For it to be semantically correct, C1 & C2 must be mutually exclusive in state A - otherwise you have non-determinism.

hth.

Comment: not homework. I am wondering if I have the same variable which I use in different guard conditions, if I should make the condition as a part of the trigger, making them into different triggers or if its ok to model it as same trigger with condition like, if (var==2) condition C1 and another one if var==3 being condition C2

Comment: thanks that cleared that up. On a related note--- if I had multiple triggers A,B which caused transitions between two states S1 and S2, would that pose any problems ? I looked into some state diagrams online and don't see any with multiple events which lead to transitions between two states... should I make this a different question ?

Comment: I would ask as separate q.  Can't think immediately why it would cause a problem but as you say, not (m)any examples out there.  Might be worth looking at the UML spec...

Comment: Guards are just for: is the request for state change is valid or not ?? and not for conditional options, conditionals are called "choice" and makes your state machine un-deterministic. @user716129